# Docker CentOS - adding EPEL

Tags: docker, yum, epel, centos8

I'm trying to get access to EPEL on CentOS (v8, Dockerhub latest).  I'm following what seems to be the recommended approach; that is, installing `epel-release`.

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM centos

RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install -y epel-release
```

But when I try to build the container, I get the following:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/6 : FROM centos
latest: Pulling from library/centos
729ec3a6ada3: Pull complete 
Digest: sha256:f94c1d992c193b3dc09e297ffd54d8a4f1dc946c37cbeceb26d35ce1647f88d9
Status: Downloaded newer image for centos:latest
 ---> 0f3e07c0138f
Step 2/6 : LABEL maintainer="rremer@medallia.com"
 ---> Running in be2f7fef5052
Removing intermediate container be2f7fef5052
 ---> 2f81a5f48a09
Step 3/6 : RUN yum update -y
 ---> Running in 441eafae5dac
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:20    
CentOS-8 - Base                                 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:20    
CentOS-8 - Extras                               0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:20    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'AppStream', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'BaseOS', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'extras', ignoring this repo.
Dependencies resolved.
Nothing to do.
Complete!
Removing intermediate container 441eafae5dac
 ---> 9410b8dede8c
Step 4/6 : RUN yum install -y epel-release
 ---> Running in 0514401a6ea3
CentOS-8 - AppStream                            0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:20    
CentOS-8 - Base                                 0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:20    
CentOS-8 - Extras                               0.0  B/s |   0  B     00:20    
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'AppStream', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'BaseOS', ignoring this repo.
Failed to synchronize cache for repo 'extras', ignoring this repo.
No match for argument: epel-release
Error: Unable to find a match
The command '/bin/sh -c yum install -y epel-release' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I am having the same issue on a VM.

Comment: Sorry, I did not.  I went another route.

Answer (score -1):

as mentioned in [this post](https://serverfault.com/questions/442088/how-do-you-answer-yes-for-yum-install-automatically) on serverfault, adding

```
assumeyes=1
```

in

```
/etc/yum.conf
```

will give you what you want.
so for the Dockerfile, you would add:

```
RUN echo "assumeyes=1" >> /etc/yum.conf
```

Comment: This does not solve the problem of not finding `epel-release` in the repository.